# I have a problem, when sending a request to the server, the reducer calls setUsers 2 times

Tags: javascript

I don't understand what the problem is.

1)I'm created friends-reducer.js

```
const FOLLOW = 'FOLLOW';
const UNFOLLOW = 'UNFOLLOW';
const SET_USERS = 'SET_USERS';

let initialState = {
  users: []
};

const FriendsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FOLLOW:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: state.users.map(u => {
          if (u.id === action.userId) {
            return { ...u, followed: true }
          }
          return u;
        })
      }

    case UNFOLLOW:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: state.users.map(u => {
          if (u.id === action.userId) {
            return { ...u, followed: false }
          }
          return u;
        })
      }

    case SET_USERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [...state.users, ...action.users]
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const followAC = (userId) => ({ type: FOLLOW, userId })

export const unfollowAC = (userId) => ({ type: UNFOLLOW, userId })

export const setUsersAC = (users) => ({ type: SET_USERS, users })

export default FriendsReducer;
```

2. Create FriendsConteiner.jsx but when i send a request, i have 2 times more users displayed on my page. I think that the reducer is launched 2 times. But I have rechecked many times that the reducer should run 1 time, but it is not so

```
    import Friends from './Friends';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { followAC, setUsersAC, unfollowAC } from '../../Redux/friends-Reduser';
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class FriendsConteiner extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.users.length === 0) {

      axios.get("https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/users").then(response => {
        this.props.setUsers(response.data.items)
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <Friends users={this.props.users}
      follow={this.props.follow}
      unfollow={this.props.unfollow}
    />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    users: state.FriendsPage.users
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    follow: (userId) => {
      dispatch(followAC(userId))
    },
    unfollow: (userId) => {
      dispatch(unfollowAC(userId))
    },
    setUsers: (users) => {
      dispatch(setUsersAC(users))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FriendsConteiner);
```

Friends.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import User from './User';

const Friends = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='Friends'>
      <div className="selectedPage">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
      </div>
      {
        props.users.map(u => <User
          followed={u.followed}
          id={u.id}
          key={u.id}
          photos={u.photos.smoll}
          fullName={u.name}
          follow={props.follow}
          unfollow={props.unfollow}
        />)
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Friends;
```

User.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import userPhoto from '../../assets/images/user.webp';

const User = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='user' key={props.id}>
      <div className='user__present'>
        <div className='user__img'><img src={props.photos != null ? props.photos : userPhoto} alt='user' /></div>
        <div className='user__followed'>{
          props.followed ?
            <button onClick={() => props.unfollow(props.id)}>unfollow</button>
            : <button onClick={() => props.follow(props.id)}>follow</button>
        }</div>
      </div>
      <div className='user__info'>
        <div className="user__name">{props.fullName}</div>
        <div className="user__status">{props.status}</div>
        <div className='user__location'>
          <div className="user__city">{"props.city"}</div>
          <div className="user__country">{"props.country"}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. Could you remove the bits that don’t matter? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think your issue is around the fact that your setUsers case is spreading whatever is already in state with the returned list from your request. I'm making the assumption that your request will send back a full list of users every time. This is likely also an issue of props not being ready when the request in CDM in FriendsConteiner is made. Is there a different spot where this request is also made higher up?

Comment: No, more requests is haven’t. I’m want that state save new users after the previous users